# .NET MVC5 хостинг на appharbor.com

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый вечер.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный алгоритм размещения проекта, основанного на темплейте .NET MVC5,  в хостинг на appharbor.com.
В проекте используется  ApplicationDbContext и DefaultConnection, затем база строится на построенных классах.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации с аппхарбора:

1. Перейдите на appharbor.com/applications
2. Создайте приложение
3. Получите урл репозитория
4. Добавьте в своем локальньном репозитории ранее полученый в роли удаленного репозитория
5. Запуште изменения

[Вот](https://blog.appharbor.com/2012/05/25/deploy-to-appharbor-using-github-for-windows) еще офф пример деплоя MVC солюшена с картинками.

Comment: Пушил я туда проект, брал бесплатный sql server, но выдает ошибку,  локально проект работает.

Comment: @Maks какая ошибка?

Comment: Когда запускаю сайт,  пишет  - Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: @Maks ну не факт, что это связано именно с БД. Причин этой ошибки множество. Смотрите логи.

Comment: Html  работает, не появляются  именно данные с бд,  и добавлять  их в базу  не выходит,  эта ошибка выскакивает.

Comment: @Maks посмотрите логи, причин возникновения ошибки при работе с БД тоже не мало.

Comment: Я  в логах не особый специалист, вы  можете сказать как правильно настраивать configuration variables  на sql server апхарбора,  если в  проекте используется DefaultConnection.

Comment: @Maks воспользуйтесь log4net, оберните проблемные места try\catch, в catch запишите текст ошибки в логи. Обычно логи пишется в директорию проекта, в принципе при желании можно вывести их в интерфейс.

Comment: В случае если в web.config стоит customererror = true я бы его оключил .. может ошибка будет более подробная.. в настройках подключения к базе точно стоит не локальная бд?

Comment: Локальная стоит, но на апхарборе же нужно как-то настроить sql server, чтобы  он верно  заменил всю строку  подключения к базе.